# How to get SESSION through Jquery im using Struts2

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I have an action named "Login.action" that puts a certain type of object in the SESSION but depending on this object i want to do something with jQuery this is my example

```
public String execute() {
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
    sesion.setAttribute(user.getprofile(), user);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

as i said i put an object in my SESSION so i want to acces later on JSP with jQuery 
(if the user's profile is "Admin" i want to make an "Admin Panel" button appear using jQuery)

Also i want to know if this is a good way to get this result or there's another (and better) way to do it

Comment: In the JSP, you have access to session attributes. What's the problem?

Comment: Why do you need javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Strut set session

```
Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.put("user","username);
```

set your user in session

```
$.session.set("user", $("#uname").val());
```

get session user

```
$.session.get('user');
```